# how to increase a field value of mysql table every some minutes automatically

Tags: mysql

I have a field in mysql table that I  want increase this field value every about 5 min (298 seconds) ,

how we could increase this field value?

thanks

Comment: you can use cron in server side languages like php

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using MySql version 5.1.6 or above, you can use the built in [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html):

```
CREATE EVENT e_update ON SCHEDULE EVERY 298 SECOND DO
  UPDATE tableName SET Col = Col + 1;
```

Or

```
CREATE EVENT e_update ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE DO
  UPDATE tableName SET Col = Col + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a php script that updates your database field however you like, then create a cron job that executes this script every five minutes.

Replace PHP with your scripting language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have a php script on your server, called by cron every 5 mins.

```
*/5 * * * * /home/whatever/updateField.php
```